# Looking or LINQ C++ in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, xml, linq

I am new to c++ and found linq to query an xml file.
I am using VS 2019 community edition.

If I use some of the example code  I get "identifier from is undefined"
the part of the code is

```
auto xml = System::Xml::Linq::XDocument::Load("Send.xml");
auto query = (from node in xml....
```

What do I need to include ?

Comment: I'm not sure C++ supports the "literal" LINQ syntax. I think it's a C# feature.

Comment: [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) is a feature of `C#` not `C++`

Comment: I found the searches a little confusing .. didn't know if I needed to add a library .. i'll try it in c# project for interest then crack on …   thank you ..